# How to evaluate a definite integral that contains a constant?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate this definite integral with a constant? $$\int_0^{a^1/4}  x^7\sqrt{a^2 - x^8} dx$$

I've never seen the constant 'a' before in this situation. But here's what a have so far at least via substitution rule:
$$u = a^2-x^8 $$

Comment: you've pretty much got it. take the derivative and substitute. I'm sure you will see

Comment: "a have" should be "I have"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the integral

$$\int_0^{a^{1/4}}  x^7\sqrt{a^2 - x^8} dx$$

As you said use the rule:

$$u = a^2-x^8 $$

$$du = -8x^7dx$$

$$x^7dx = \frac{du}{-8}$$

Also our bounds must be changed:

When $x = a^{1/4}$, $u = a^2 - a^2 = 0$

When $x = 0$, $u = a^2 - 0 = a^2$

So using this:

$$\int_0^{a^{1/4}}  x^7\sqrt{a^2 - x^8} dx = \frac{-1}{8}\int_0^{a^{1/4}}  \sqrt{u} du = \frac{-1}{8}\left[\frac{2u^{3/2}}{3}\right]_{a^2}^{0} = \frac{-1}{8}\left(0 - \frac{2a^3}{3}\right) = \frac{a^3}{12}$$

Comment if you have questions.
$$$$

Comment: $du = -8x^7\color{red}{dx}$

Comment: ty for the error. fixed it

Comment: and the next line

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{4}}x^{7}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{8}}dx$$
$$u=a^{2}-x^{8}\Rightarrow du=-8x^{7}dx\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{1}{8x^{7}}du$$
$$\int_{0}^{a^{\frac{1}{4}}}x^{7}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{8}}dx=-\frac{1}{8}\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}du=-\frac{1}{12}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\mid =-\frac{1}{12}(a^{2}-x^{8})^{\frac{3}{2}}\mid_{x=0}^{x=a^{\frac{1}{4}}}\textrm{}=\frac{1}{12}a^{3}$$